# Smart contract will not deploy to my private blockchain when using Remix IDE

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, transactions, remix, private-blockchain

So I'm a complete newbie and trying to deploy my first smart contract to a local Ethereum blockchain. I'm doing this on a Windows machine.

I have created a private blockchain using geth, made an account and started mining. The account is unlocked.
This is the command I use to start the node:

```
geth --datadir "%my_node_path%" --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" console 2>console.log
```

Then I installed the remix-ide node module and created a simple smart contract.
It compiles, so no problem there.

In order to connect the Remix IDE to my blockchain, I changed the environment to Web3 provider. Seems that the connection works as the account ID shows up correctly and the ether amount updates as I mine.

[image: Screenshot of remix IDE environment and account]

Now, if I listen on the network, the console shows the mined blocks, but when I try to deploy my contract, the Remix console shows this:

> creation of greeter pending...
>
> [block:1746 -  0 transactions]

Then if I do `txpool.status` from the command line on my blockchain, it doesn't show the transaction:

> txpool.status {   pending: 0,   queued: 0 }

**Why isn't the smart contract deploying?** I am strictly following a tutorial. Have been trying to find an answer for the past day, with no luck.

Comment: Do you mean `geth` console or `Remix` console?  Try running `geth` with `--verbosity 5` and see what happens in `geth` console when you try to deploy your contract.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant the Remix console. I've edited the question. I tried running geth with --verbosity 5, but it does not seem to show anything when I tried to deploy the contract